# Reading .java source file with Python

Tags: python

Is it possible to read .java files with Python? I want to handle them as text and search for some words in there. I am using the filedialog module with tkinter.
Here is a snippet:

```
name = filedialog.askopenfile(initialdir="D:/",
    filetypes=(("Java Source File", "*.java"), ("All Files", "*.*")),
    title="Choose a file")

print(name)

f = open(name, "r")
print(f.read())
```

The content of name is:

```
<_io.TextIOWrapper name='D:/test.java' mode='r' encoding='cp1250'>
```

The exception:

```
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not _io.TextIOWrapper
```

Comment: A java source file is a text file like any other. What fails, exactly?

Comment: Are you getting any exceptions?

Comment: Please check the update of my post.

Comment: Why can't you just do `name.read()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see from your print statement, `askopendialog` returns a `TextIOWrapper`, not a string.

At that point you can read from it directly

```
print(name.read())
```

And maybe, at that point, rename the variable to something more sensible, like `source_file` or something similar.